# Return @ResponseBody in one case and a ModelAndView in another

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have a spring controller method. It's meant to programmatically sign up user (through a single sign on process from another system within the product). It works by getting user data, validating it, creating a user account if it doesnot exist, communicate back to the other system a shared token, and then authenticating the user. There is a handshake process going on, but to get to to the bottom of the problem. I want the same method to return a string if the user is not existing in the system, and return a `ModelAndView` if they are already registered.

Possible solutions (but cannot execute them):

- The returned string (in the case of the first time user) is going to be read using an `HttpURLConnection` input stream. So if there is a way to put data in ModelAndView object, and then read it using the input stream, then I am set.
- I can return the string and read it OK using the input stream by making the return type as `@ResponseBody String`, however, I cannot return a view when it is an existing user.

Ideally, I would return a model and view, but the other system is not spring, and so it won't understand it.

To summarize, one method that does two things, if the user the a first time user, it returns a string to another system with an encryption token, which the other system will use in an iframe to authenticate the user. 

Need to return a string in one case to be read using an input stream reader in another system, and in the case of an existing user, a view needs to be returned to be read using spring itself.

Please let me know if any of this isnot clear.

**EDIT:** Is there a way to return an http response (something like http servlet response) that is generic enough and works inside and outside of spring. This will also solve my problem.

Comment: How do you go from your `String` return to the iframe page for authentication? (Is it possible to return a `ModelAndView` then parse it using JS to get the data into your other system?)

Comment: @zshooter, when I return a string I dont go the iframe yet, because it still saving data for the user. What happens is that a post request is made using `HttpURLConnection`, and then the response is read. The iframe comes in the second step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a method can have only one return type, so you will need to forward the request to another controller method. Which controller method can depend on the result of your authentication ...

```
    @RequestMapping ...
    public String handleRequest() {
        if(valid){
           return "forward:/path_to_my_another_controller";
        }else {
           return "forward:/somewhere_else";
        }
    }
```

Comment: the intention wasnot to return two types in the same method, as I explained in the question, I want a return type that works for my requirements. Your solution sounds promising, I am going to give it a try.